# Running SonarQube on Azure App Service gives an access denied error when starting the service

Tags: java, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm using the ARM template located at https://github.com/vanderby/SonarQube-AzureAppService to deploy SonarQube to Azure App Service. After deployment when accessing the website I see the following in the logs:

```
5:13:06 PM Starting HttpPlatformHandler Script
5:13:06 PM HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT is: 20471
5:13:06 PM Searching for sonar.properties file
5:13:14 PM File found at: D:\home\site\wwwroot\sonarqube-7.7\conf\sonar.properties
5:13:14 PM Writing to sonar.properties file
5:13:14 PM Searching for wrapper.conf file
5:13:15 PM File found at: D:\home\site\wwwroot\sonarqube-7.7\conf\wrapper.conf
5:13:15 PM Writing to wrapper.conf file
5:13:15 PM Searching for StartSonar.bat
5:13:16 PM File found at: D:\home\site\wwwroot\sonarqube-7.7\bin\windows-x86-64\StartSonar.bat
5:13:16 PM Executing StartSonar.bat
wrapper  | Unable to set the process priority:  Access is denied. (0x0)
wrapper  | Attempt to set the console title failed: The handle is invalid. (0x6)
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
wrapper  | Startup failed: Timed out waiting for a signal from the JVM.
wrapper  | JVM did not exit on request, terminated
wrapper  | JVM Restarts disabled.  Shutting down.
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I'm getting all kinds of access denied errors when I try to edit files through Kudu so it seems a general permission issue.

Any idea what's going on? I've Googled for the issue but haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: How did you deploy the site? I just deploy from the github , it worked and then deploy with the .ps script also worked. However the path in the .ps need be changed to .\.\wwwroot and copy the HttpPlatformHandlerStartup.ps1 and web.config to wwwroot folder.

Comment: @GeorgeChen I did the deploy from GitHub. I've also setup a CI/CD from Azure DevOps but then I startd running into access denied errors so i came back to this sample but it also doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @WouterdeKort have you solved this issue? I'm having the same problem now. Where should I look to start resolving it?

Comment: @AlexanderZhidkov Sorry but I haven't resolved this yet.

Answer (score 0):

This log may be from a second startup. If the site is hit multiple times before the app service knows its started it'll try to start SQ multiple times and only one will succeed. I just tried the template from GitHub and it worked with SQ 7.7.

Couple other things to note:
 - Free and Shared environments aren't supported. SQ doesn't start on them. You need B1 or higher.
 - The initial startup time may take up to 5 minutes, especially on a B1 app service.
 - You can find additional information at wwwroot\sonarqube-x.x\logs\web.log and \sonar.log

Thanks for finding the template useful!

Comment: I still can't figure it out. I'm deploying to a standard app service so the SKU should be right. I've seen it working before and I know it takes a long time to boot the first time. The logs aren't created because of the access denied errors I keep running into. The only log that gets created is in the LogFiles folder on Kudu and that shows the access denied errors.